# Installing CM 13 OTA causes so many app crashes that I can't do anything on my phone. Can I save my data?

Tags: ota-update, crashes, cyanogenmod

I had cyanogenmod 12 on my Samsung S4 mini phone, and I upgraded OTA to cyanogenmod 13. After the update Google play services was crashing all the time. I tried downloading and installing GApps through the recovery mode but it only made it worse. Now the crash pop ups are so many that I can't do anything on the phone anymore. "Unfortunately Setup Wizard has stopped" is the one that shows up the most.

Is there any way to fix it without resetting everything? And if resetting is the only option, can I still save the data?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Which particular build was it? To which particular build did you move to? Did you update your GApps? How? Did you do things in accordance with this post: http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/a-marshmallowy-cm?

Comment: I am not sure what build it was or is. The 12 was the stable one. The 13 was the one that was offered OTA. I did not follow what the post said - I saw there was an update and I naively clicked it. When it started to have problems I downloaded  OpenGApps ARM 6.0 nano.

Comment: With so many crashes, I don know how to look at the version of CM13. The pop ups come one after the other and I can't do anything on the phone. The version that was there before I unfortunately do not remember.

Answer (score 1):

Try booting into recovery mode and enabling MTP, and then get your data from there.

What happened was that the Gapps were incompatible with your OS, since you were using Lollipop gapps on Marshmallow. Once you flashed Gapps, it was already too late, since they need to be flashed on first boot.

Once you have your data, factory reset and flash the packages in this order: CM -> Gapps -> Whatever else (SuperSU?). Make sure that they are flashed one after each other. Do NOT reboot until Gapps is flashed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @PoisonNinja! How do I enable MTP from recovery, and once I done, how do I get my data?

Comment: It is so frustrating! I am sure I must not have been the only person who clicked the bloody thing without paying attention! (or, in my case, I have to admit it was more without knowing what I am doing ...)

Comment: @Sininho, go to the main TWRP menu, tap on Mount. Make sure that Data is checked. Then, tap on Enable MTP. It should show up on your computer.